# Silent collection create to stop request

Tags: backbone.js

Is it possible to do a silent `create` with a collection? I want to do this because I have a collection that won't be having it's state persisted on a server.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the Backbone source there is not an option to prevent the model.save() within collection.create(), it will always save the model to the server.

You could just do it like this:

```
collection.add( new Model({id:1}) );
```

You don't need the logic of collection.create() if you do not want to save the model to the server because there is no possible error in the ajax request and so you do not need the logic to only add the model if the save was successful.